# How to nest columns in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) it's stated that to nest content with the grid system I must add a new `.row` and set of `.col-sm-*` columns within an existing `.col-sm-*` column. However, nesting just the `.col-sm-*` columns w/o adding a new `.row` seems to work as well.
I wonder what difference does the new `.row` make?

Answer (score 1):

You can have columns nested in another column but they should generally be inside a row. **The rows have negative margins to account for the padding on the columns, so if you have columns nested inside columns without a row in between, it will mess up the alignment of your page.**

Answer (score 0):

`Rows` are used to create horizontal groups of columns. Rows also help in keeping the elements in the same line. Doing this will make all the elements in a well-structured format.

Try this both and you we will understand by yourself.

> USING ROW

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

> WITHOUT USING ROW

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```